# Is there a way to specify "USE INDEX" or "FORCE INDEX" in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is it possible to specify "USE INDEX" or "FORCE INDEX" in CodeIgniter, other than using

```
$this->db->query()
```

What I mean is if it's possible to insert "FORCE INDEX" somewhere in one of ActiveRecord's methods.

Comment: Not as far as I know. I see two workarounds: 1: Extend the AR class to allow inserting a `FORCE INDEX` and 2: sanitize your data properly, build your own query and use `$this->db->query()
` to get the results

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `from()` active record method to add this in queries like this:

```
$this->db->like('name', 'user', 'after')->from('users use index (name)')->get();
```

produces sql query like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM (`users` use index (name)) WHERE  `name`  LIKE 'user%'
```

One caveat is that the `from()` method tries to find identifiers and multiple tables so adding one or more `,` to it's input is most likely to end up as an SQL syntax error.